# Can't write into a file using fstream - I can't seem to get why

Tags: c++

I need to create a program using graph theory which takes as an input multiple undirected graphs and writes out either YES if it is a complete graph or NO if it is not a complete graph.

E.g.
for:

```
2 //number of graps
3 //number of lines of the first graph's matrix
0 1 1 //the first graph's matrix
1 0 1
1 1 0
4 //number of lines of the second graph's matrix
0 1 1 1 //the second graph's matrix
1 0 0 1
1 0 0 1
1 1 1 0
```

It should output:

```
YES
NO
```

I solved it this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream f("graf_complet.in");
ofstream g("graf_complet.out");

int verif(int matrice[][100], int t)
{
    int c = 0;
    bool ok = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++)
    {
        c = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= t; j++)
        {
            if (matrice[i][j] == 1)
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
        if (c != (t - 1))
        {
            ok = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (ok == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int g, c = 0, t, matrice[100][100];
    f >> g;
    while (c != g)
    {
        f >> t;
        for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= t; j++)
            {
                f >> matrice[i][j];
            }
        }
        if (verif(matrice, t))
        {
            g << "YES";
        }
        else
        {
            g << "NO";
        }
        c++;
    }
}
```

Using cout instead of writing into files works, and I seem to get the proper results. When I try to write into the file with g<< (as I'm supposed to) I get:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2297   '<<': illegal, right operand has type 'const char [3]'  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\x\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp 52  
Error   C2297   '<<': illegal, right operand has type 'const char [3]'  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\x\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp 56  
Error (active)  E2140   expression must have integral or unscoped enum type ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\x\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp 52  
Error (active)  E2140   expression must have integral or unscoped enum type ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\x\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp 56
```

I can't get why this happens tbh. It is not the first time I write into files this way and I've never encountered this. I think it might be something about the fact that the file which I'm taking the input from (so basically f>>) is not closed, it is still open.

Is that the reason?

If so, how can I still make the program work? If not, what is the issue causing the error?

Thanks.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  Either rename `int g` so it doesn't hide `ofstream g` or use `::g` when you want to refer to the global `g`.

Comment: [Pro Tip] This is why variable names should be descriptive.  It's a lot harder to make this mistake when you do so.

Comment: If you're using VS (which I think you are, from the errors), turn on `/W4`, or more specifically [`/w4"4459"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4459?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @NathanOliver oh my god I'm so sorry. I didn't realise I had an int with the same name.

Comment: @ChrisMM where should I turn that on and how does that help?

Comment: Go to your project's properties, then "C/C++". You can turn on `W4` from the "General" tab (warning level). Specific warnings can be done in the "Command Line" tab. That warning would have told you that you are hiding `g`

Comment: Where did you declare the variables `t` and `matrice[100][100]` in your sample code?

Comment: @ChrisMM sorry for the late response, I knew that the problem was solved and I forgot about it. I activated it. Thanks a lot.